# what font to use in quotes and warning advices

Tags: fonts, typography

I wonder what font I should use to my quotes environment, or how to differentiate it really from the mass of the text.

I will use this environment in advices, warning (things to do or not, what to take care of…).

There will be also a few actual quotes. But most will be warnings.

I use sfserif for the main body of text. The general subject of the text is GPG, so the crypto software, and I aim to give advices, remarks about how you should use it or not.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: This question isn’t about TeX in particular, and it’s impossible to give a reasonable opinion without knowing the subject matter of the document and the font chosen for the main body of the text.  Can you rework the question into something answerable?

Comment: In addition, I would caution against using `quote` or `quotation` or whatever this way. Indeed, it does not sound as if a single environment should be used for all of these things at all. I would create distinct environments for distinct purposes, even if you want them all to have the same definition. That way, if you change your mind and want to distinguish them later, it is easy to do so. For example, environments `advice`, `warning` etc. and then use `quote` or `quotation` for actual quotes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the remark. Here are my thoughts (debate is open, I am asking for your advices, so I really appreciate your comment):


- The quotes still need to be set better. So I need at least those…
- I think the advices and remarks as quotations from myself.

If you think I am wrong, ok. But still, I need advice about the best fontes for these cases (at least actual quotes and warning).

Comment: Please post a small, compilable document which illustrates what you are doing and what you want to achieve. I have no idea what `sfserif` is or where it is from or how you are using it. Presumably you are using XeTeX/LuaTeX? Are you using `fontspec`? What class are you using? What does a page of the document look like? How long are the pieces of advice? Should they break at page breaks?

Comment: The documentation of the `bclogo` package may give you some ideas.  Also `tcolorbox`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% manual p. 14
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{advice}[1][Usage]{colback=blue!5!white, colframe=blue!75!black, fonttitle=\bfseries, title=Tip~\thetcbcounter: #1}
\newtcolorbox{warning}[1][]{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black, fonttitle=\bfseries, colbacktitle=red!85!black, enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, title=Warning! #1}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{advice}
    Some advice about using the software.
  \end{advice}
  \begin{advice}[Encrypting]
    Don't forget the password!
  \end{advice}
  \begin{warning}
    Really important thing to do.
  \end{warning}
  \begin{warning}[Read this!]
    Another really crucial thing.
  \end{warning}
  \begin{quotation}
    \kant[1]
  \end{quotation}
  \begin{quote}
    \kant[2]
  \end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple examples]

Comment: I will try to use that.